# Teradata - Record split based on date range and timestamp

Tags: sql, date, teradata, overlapping

There is a scenario where we have records with overlapping dates and we need to split the records based on dates, considering the recently updated record. 
Consider the below examples -

Scenario 1:

### Input

```
Source  Destination     Begin_Date   End_Date     Last_Updated      Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC      123            3/15/2015    12/15/2015   3/17/2015 9:18    50
ABC      123            4/15/2015    5/15/2015    3/18/2015 2:31    44
```

### Ouput

```
Source  Destination     Begin_Date   End_Date      Value
----------------------------------------------------------
ABC       123           3/15/2015    4/14/2015     50
ABC       123           4/15/2015    5/15/2015     44
ABC       123           5/16/2015    12/15/2015    50
```

Scenario 2:

### Input

```
Source  Destination     Begin_Date   End_Date    Last_Updated     Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC       123           3/15/2015    12/15/2015  3/17/2015 9:18    50
ABC       123           4/15/2015    12/15/2015  3/18/2015 2:31    44
```

### Ouput

```
Source  Destination     Begin_Date   End_Date     Value
--------------------------------------------------------
ABC       123           3/15/2015    4/14/2015     50
ABC       123           4/15/2015    12/15/2015    44
```

Scenario 3:

### Input

```
Source   Destination    Begin_Date   End_Date     Last_Updated     Value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC        123          4/15/2015    12/15/2015   3/17/2015 9:18   50 
ABC        123          3/15/2015    12/15/2015   3/18/2015 2:31   44
```

### Ouput

```
Source   Destination    Begin_Date    End_Date     Value
--------------------------------------------------------
ABC        123          3/15/2015     12/15/2015     44
```

Comment: Does the data always arrive in sequence? If yes, then it can save you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mostly about the first scenario only, which, I think, is the most complex. I believe rest of the scenarios can be built around the first scenario's queries with some alterations, not to mention that I'm too lazy to create the entire solution.

You will also need to incorporate the `Last_Updated` column into this logic according to your requirements.

Simplest logic would be to ignore the `End_Date`. Sort the data and use `Begin_Date` of each row as the `End_Date` in its preceding row. Then discard rows where `Begin_Date` of current record = `End_Date` of preceding record. I believe this will handle all scenarios besides the first one.

For the first scenario, you need to identify the overlaps. I guess it can be achieved by joining the sets, but that will be tedious and expensive. I was able to identify the overlaps using windowing operation (the 2nd set in the `UNION` clause of the following query) where X is the table containing data for scenario 1

```
SELECT  SRC, 
        DEST,
        BEGIN_DATE,
        END_DATE,
        VAL
FROM    X
UNION
SELECT  SRC,
        DEST,
        MIN(END_DATE) OVER( PARTITION BY SRC, DEST
                            ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE DESC ROWS 1 PRECEDING) + 1,
        END_DATE,
        VAL
FROM    X
QUALIFY MIN(END_DATE) OVER( PARTITION BY SRC, DEST
                            ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE DESC ROWS 1 PRECEDING) < END_DATE
```

Storing those results in table z, One can build the required history using

```
SELECT  SRC,
        DEST,
        BEGIN_DATE,
        CAST(COALESCE(MAX(BEGIN_DATE) OVER( PARTITION BY SRC, DEST
                            ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE ASC
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING),
             END_DATE) AS DATE) - 1 AS END_DATE,
        VAL
FROM    Z
```